# xcode swift считывание json файла

Tags: json, xcode, swift4

Почему в моем коде не считывает данные с json файла полностью, например до определенного места берет данные и дальше пустые, каждый раз бывает по разному`

```
func getDataFromJson(){
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "milQ", ofType: "txt") else {return}
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
do{

let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
// print(json)
guard let array = json as? [Any] else {return}
for all in array{
guard let allQuestions = all as?[String: Any] else{return}
// Здесь идут if
}
catch{
print("Error")}
```

`

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите, срочно надо! Я новичок в разработке

Comment: Срочно - это не на этот ресурс

Comment: Тупанул короче теперь английский не принимает вопрос только после 90 мин

Comment: Почему txt? Почему используете в Swift JSONSerialization, а не Codable?